# Geolocalization user search: Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I am using the Twitter API to search for the users using the hashtag **#developer** and within **Mumbai** region.

Based on the information for the parameters to pass to get the required result, from the [Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), the resulting search url is:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/search.json?q=%23developers&geocode=19.298572,72.871817,1mi
```

However, the results of the users I receive are from Amsterdam,LA, prague and else where.
How can I localize the results to only **Mumbai** area? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users/search` does not accept a `geocode` parameter. See [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search).

You can use `search/tweets` which does use `geocode`. See [doc](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets). This will return tweets, not users. You can extract the user's `screen_name` from the tweets.

Comment: How can I paginate over the results? A maximum of 100 tweets are returned in 1 request, how can I get all?

Comment: Also, The search index has a 7-day limit. No tweets will be found for a date older than one week. Is it possible to bypass this and get older tweets?

Comment: Pagination is done by using the `max_id` parameter with successive requests. First, get the `id` of the last tweet that was returned. Then, for your next request set `max_id` to the value of `id` minus one. It is not possible to get tweets older than one week using the free API.